# Trying to sort a list using bootstrap and js

Tags: javascript, html, spring, html-table, hl7-fhir

[Here is a image of the table i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5nCE.png)

Im trying to order a list with names of patients i get from the fhir example datebase. i have been working on this for at least 10 hours now am im really frustrated. i found a w3c example code for sorting the table data, it works when i use their examples, but not when i include mine.

i basically tried everything. 
javascript DOES work in my project

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>



    <title>Welcome to the Template-Engine</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <#include "header.ftl">
        <!-- common properties are put in one single header file -->


     <style>
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th {
  cursor: pointer;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}
</style>

</head>

<body class="htwg">



        <h1>Welcome to 0000 FHIR</h1>
        <h2>Searching for Patients</h2>
        <p>Using FHIR ${p_repo} - corresponding information at ${p_info}</p>
        <p>Overall Number of patients: ${p_total}</p>



        <div> 

            <fieldset>

                <legend>Patient suchen</legend>
                    <form action="/patient2/addPatient" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            Vorname: <input type="text" name="vorname" placeholder="Vorname" class="form-control" /> <br/>
                            Nachname: <input type="text" name="nachname" placeholder="Nachname" class="form-control" /> <br/>
                            Geburtsdatum: <input type="date" name="date" placeholder="..." class="form-control" />  <br/>
                            <input type="submit" value="Suchen" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg"/>
                        </div>


                    </form>
            </fliedset>

            </div>






        <table class="js-sort-table" id="myTable" data-sort-order="desc">
            <thead>

                 <tr>
                     <th scope="col" onclick="sortTable(0)">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col" onclick="sortTable(1)">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col" onclick="sortTable(2)">Gender</th>
                    <th scope="col onclick="sortTable(3)">Birthdate</th>

                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
          <!-- Liste, mit den Suchkriterien, alle 3 müssen eingegeben sein (Keines darf NULL sein)-->
                <#list patientList as p>


                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" onclick="sortTable(0)" >${(p.id)!"NA"}</th>
                        <th scope="col" onclick="sortTable(1)" >${(p.name)!"NA"}</th>
                        <th scope="col" onclick="sortTable(2)" >${(p.gender)!"NA"}</th>
                        <th scope="col" onclick="sortTable(3)" >${(p.birthdate)!"NA"}</th>

                    </tr>

                </#list>


            </tbody>
        </table>


    </div>
    <script>
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc"; 
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;      
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>



</body>

</html>
```

it sounds dumb but i have to get this done for uni and im really on the edge to cry.

Comment: Try solution given on below link.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes even little typos cause big problems. Look at the 4th  col in your #myTable table table head. Should be scope="col"

Doesn't sound dumb, we've all been there!
Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, i think i have used scope="col". Where exactly do you mean?

Comment: `<th scope="col onclick="sortTable(3)">Birthdate</th>`

Comment: In your html, the fourth column of the `<thead>` is missing the close quote immediately following `col`. So it reads `scope="col onclick"` instead of `scope="col"`.